# Get time in filename save in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word macro that is saving the doc as a pdf and emailing it.  The only problem is that it will overwrite itself on the network drive.  I can't figure out how to get the seconds into the filename with the code below.

Thanks for the help!

```
dte = Date
savedName = "Night Orders - " & Format(dte, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Response = MsgBox("Save and email the current document?", vbOKCancel, "Are you sure?")
    If Response = vbOK Then

        savePath = saveDir & saveName & ".pdf"
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=savePath, _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
            From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, _
            KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: Have you looked at the VBA function `Time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
savedName = "Night Orders - " & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss")
```